# program received signal SIGSEGV while using scanf

Tags: c++, memory, scanf, segmentation-fault

Im working on an algorithm in C++, and im trying to speed up its execution by changing the cin to scanf. But when I did that, I started having SIGSEGV errors.

```
    int main(){

    int nominal;
    int check;
    string b;
    int x;
    int a;

    int i = 0;

    //cin >> a;
    scanf ("%d",&a);
    for (int i = 0; i<a; i++){
        //cin >> b;
        scanf("%s",&b); 
        std::priority_queue < int > Q;
        std::priority_queue < int, std::vector < int >, std::greater < int > > moneyBox; 
        while (b!="0"){
```

The code stops working while entering the first while. Any tips on how to fix it?

Comment: You cannot use `std::string` with `scanf("%s",&b);`. Use `getline()` or `cin >> b;` instead.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Not entirely true. He can use ``resize(big_enough)`` and then ``data()`` member and then set the size to the correct value later on.

Comment: Apart of that technicality - you speed up nothing with that change, here. Unless you are a light-speed typer, the time it takes to write the input makes  the time difference - if there is any for your change negligible.

Comment: @BitTickler The algorithm  is being checked by an online judge

Answer (score 0):

[`scanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) uses formatting chars that correspond to predetermined types.  `"%s"` is meant to store a null terminated c-string in a `char` array.  `scanf()` will therefore misinterpret the address of the c++ string `&b` to be a valid `char*` pointing to a preallocated array of char of sufficient size.  This will corrupt memory and might cause UB.

Comment: You can't "cause" UB. Rather, the program _has_ behaviour that is undefined.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ok, I've reformulated

Comment: Still says "might cause UB". Oh well.

Comment: Thanks for the clear up. The whole algorithm is based around strings being converted to ints (depending on what is actually in the input), so the fix might take me more time then I thought